# Assign view IDs in XML, access programmatically as integers

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to be able to assign view IDs in XML, but access them programmatically as integers for the sake of iterating over them easily.

Here's the direction I was going which does not work:

**values/value.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <integer name="int1">101</integer>
    <integer name="int2">102</integer>
    ...
    <integer name="int10">110</integer>
</resources>
```

**layout/fancy_dialog_fragment.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...etc.>

    <Button android:id="@integer/int1" ... />
    <Button android:id="@integer/int2" ... />
    ...
    <Button android:id="@integer/int10" ...etc. />


</LinearLayout>
```

**FancyDialogFragment.java:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    button[i] = (Button) getDialog().findViewById(100+i);
    button[i].setText("foo");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

This goes into res/values/arrays.xml (you can call it whatever you want of course):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="myIds">
        <item>int1</item>
        <item>int2</item>
        <item>int3</item>
        <item>int4</item>
        <item>int5</item>
        <item>int6</item>
        <item>int7</item>
        <item>int8</item>
        <item>int9</item>
        <item>int10</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

That's how the layout looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...etc.>
    <Button android:id="@+id/int1" .../>
    <Button android:id="@+id/int2" .../>
    <Button android:id="@+id/int3" .../>
    <Button android:id="@+id/int4" .../>
    <Button android:id="@+id/int5" .../>
    <Button android:id="@+id/int6" .../>
    <Button android:id="@+id/int7" .../>
    <Button android:id="@+id/int8" .../>
    <Button android:id="@+id/int9" .../>
    <Button android:id="@+id/int10" .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

And there's the code:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String packageName = getPackageName();
String[] ids = res.getStringArray(R.array.myIds);
for (String id : ids) {
    int idInt = res.getIdentifier(id, "id", packageName);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(idInt);
    button.setText("foo");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the file `res/values/ids.xml` and declare the ids there:

```
<resources>
    <item name="id_1" type="id"/>
    <item name="id_2" type="id"/>
    <!-- etc. -->
</resources>
```

Next create an integer array, in the same file or elsewhere (like in `res/values/arrays.xml`) and use the ids as items:

```
<integer-array name="my_ids">
    <item>@id/id_1</item>
    <item>@id/id_2</item>
    <!-- etc. -->
</integer-array>
```

Now you can use the ids in your xml using `android:id="@id/id_1"` (without the `+`), and also use the integer array in code:

```
int[] myIds = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.my_ids);
for (int i = 0; ...) {
    int id = myIds.getResourceId(i, 0);
    // do something with id
}
```

Comment: What would be the advantage over my solution? Just curious because what I can see it's an extra step (ids.xml, arrays.xml, layout and code) without real advantage but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I prefer to be explicit about iterating an array of integer IDs and not relying on strings. Here you can use the same integer values everywhere and not rely on the string tokens being correct. I also think N calls to `getIdentifier()` are probably more expensive than one call to `getIntArray()`.

Comment: Are you sure this works: <item>@id/id_1</item>? I tested it and the code always returns 0 but not the actual id?

Comment: To make this work we must obtain `TypedArray` using such line `TypedArray typedIds = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.my_ids);`. And then in a cycle to get the integers we can call `typedIds.getResourceId(i, 0);`.

Comment: Thanks @StanMots, I've updated the answer with your additions.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to do like this. Your buttons ids are so similar. try this code:

> for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
>       int idInt = res.getIdentifier(id, String.format("int%d", i), packageName);
>       Button button = (Button) findViewById(idInt);
>       button.setText("foo");
>   }

Comment: res.getIdentifier(id, String.format("int%d", i) should be res.getIdentifier(String.format("int%d", i), "id" and yes that would work too but is less flexible.